# Using Resource from different package in Jersey Application

Tags: java, servlets, resources, jersey

I have developed an SDK that uses a Resource in a rest package:

```
package com.example.some.package.rest;
...
@Path("/health")
public class HealthResource {

    public HealthResource() {
        // some code
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getHealth() {
        // some code to return health
    }
}
```

Then I have another package with an Application implementation:

```
package com.example.different.package.rest;
...
public class HealthApplication extends Application {

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return Sets.<Object> newHashSet(new HealthResource());
    }
}
```

However, this will not work for me. I have to use another wrapper class:

```
package com.example.different.package.rest;
...
@Path("")
public class WrapperHealthResource extends HealthResource {
    public WrapperHealthResource() {
        super();
    }
}
```

If I use WrapperHealthResource in the HealthApplication instead of HealthResource, then it works fine.

I think it's pretty useless to have this extra class. How can I get rid of this complexity?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Are you just wanting your `HealthResource` to be a `Singleton`?

Comment: Yes. I only need it to be created once and not on every call, and I don't want to have to wrap it to get it to work. Also, I am using Jersey 1.18.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I haven't been able to test this on `Jersey 1.8` - I only have a `2.7` test harness around. But the API hasn't really changed in this area so you should be OK.

If you only need the `Application` class to enforce the `Singleton` of your `HealthResource` resource and nothing else, then I would just annotate the class with `@Singleton` and remove your `Application` class. That's the easiest.

I'm not able to reproduce your issue with `2.7`, so this may be an issue with `1.8` (unlikely in this instance) or how you're registering your `Application`. If you want to post the rest of your code, I might be able to help.

Will

PS - if you're able, upgrade to 2.8.